# S3TC / DTXn patents

Tags: opengl, textures, dds, patents

I just wrote a **DTXn** loader in my OpenGL engine to support **.dds** files (i.e. via `glCompressedTexImage2D`) and generally employ *texture compression in GPU*.

I've also found that using **S3TC** leads to patent issues.
I've done some searching and found that on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S3_Texture_Compression):

```
The patent on S3 Texture Compression expires on October 2, 2017.
```

Does this message means that in about 1 year S3TC algorithms could be open-sourced without patents and could be used freely and should just wait?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That patents shouldn't touch you (as mere user of OpenGL api) at all, unless you're writing own OpenGL/D3D implementations and adding texture compression support there. Then you'll have to pay attention.

Comment: i see.. so these patents are only for custom S3TC implementations and not if you're just using whatever supported by your GPU via some api. Thanx!